# Conditional expectation of a geometric Brownian motion with a power?

Tags: brownian-motion, conditional-expectation

Let $X_T$ satisfies a time-dependent geometric Brownian motion:
$$
\frac{d X_s}{X_s}= \mu_s ds+\sigma_s dB_s,~t\leq s\leq T.
$$

Could I write a conditional expectation of $X_T^\gamma$ in the following form:
$$
{\rm E}_t[X_T^{\gamma}]={\rm exp}\left({\rm E}_t[\log X_T^\gamma]+\frac12{\rm Var}_t(\log X_T^\gamma)\right)~???
$$

Thank you very much!

Comment: What are your thoughts on the matter?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/It%C3%B4%27s_lemma

Comment: You can actually compute he expectations of $X_t^{\gamma}$ in closed form.